# Add a UITableView Edit button to the toolbar in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, edit, toolbar

I have a `UIControllerView` which contains 2 tables, each having a separate controller. One of the table contains items that can be deleted.

By default the edit button can be added to the **Navigation Bar** adding the below to the `UITableViewController` in the `viewDidLoad()`:

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()`

But I need this edit button in the bottom **Toolbar**. I tried this:

Created an outlet from the toolbar button to the `UIViewController` file owned as follows:

```
class foo: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var deleteUserCategoriesButton: UIBarButtonItem!

...

override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        toobarButton = list2TableController.editButtonItem() 
        // list2TableController is the UITableViewController of the table of which items are deletable

}

...

}
```

This does not work. What would be the right way to do this in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an IBAction from the toolbarButton.  In the action call the tableViews `setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated animate: Bool)` method.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this! Thanks!